# DB2 CASE WHEN THEN adding two extra nulls to all values

Tags: sql, db2, case

I got a strange question sent to me today from a junior programmer.

In a DB2 SQL statement he switched a

```
select [Value]
```

The old result was

```
AAAAAA
CCCCCC
BBBBBB
DDDDDDDDDDD
EE
```

to

```
select 
CASE [Value] 
  WHEN 'AAAAAA'     
    THEN 'AAAA'          
  WHEN 'BBBBBB'                  
    THEN 'BBBBBBBB'          
  ELSE [Value]                
  END
```

The new result is

```
..AAAA............
..CCCCCC
..BBBBBBBB........
..DDDDDDDDDDD
..EE
```

where . represents a null

I want to understand what caused two extra nulls to appear in the nonselected values?

Comment: A null? You are talking about *one* column containing '..AAAA............
', right? So are you talking of blanks? Or binary zeros? So suddenly there are two leading characters added to each value retrieved plus several trailing characters for the literals given?

Comment: I wasn't aware that DB2 supported square braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What DB2 version and platform?
Is this statement being run directly in a SQL client interface?  Or is it in a stored procedure whose results is being interpreted by something?

To me, it looks the data type being returned has been changed from fixed length CHAR to VARCHAR and whatever is reading the results is still processing it as CHAR.

String literals are always interpreted as VARCHAR.

If that's the case, either correct the calling app or convert the VARCHAR to CHAR.

```
select 
CASE [Value] 
  WHEN 'AAAAAA'     
    THEN CHAR('AAAA', 30)          
  WHEN 'BBBBBB'                  
    THEN CHAR('BBBBBBBB', 30)          
  ELSE [Value]                
END
```

Comment: "String literals are always interpreted as VARCHAR" That makes sense. Thank you!